# Differential operators: Exterior derivative vs Covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, exterior-derivative

The classical differential operators in vector calculus can be expressed via differential forms:
$$\mathrm{grad}f=\mathrm{d}f$$
$$\mathrm{div}X=\star\mathrm{d}\star (X^{\flat})$$
$$\mathrm{curl}X=(\star\mathrm{d}(X^{\flat}))^{\sharp}$$
But they can also be expressed via the covariant derivative:
$$(\mathrm{grad}f)_i=\nabla_if$$
$$\mathrm{div}X= \nabla_iX^i $$
$$(\mathrm{curl}X)^i=\epsilon^{ijk}\nabla_jX_k$$
My question is now if the two expressions are equal when the connection is torsion-free or do we need stricter conditions?